# Identify Specific PCB Component

Tags: pcb, identification, components

I have identified and tested all the components on this board apart from one.  Can someone identify the component please?

I believe it may be faulty as all the other components seem to test ok.

[image: Component]

Comment: Measure forward an back resistance. If <<1Ω both ways, it's likely a fuse.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik  I suspect this component has failed, therefore if so,  am I am correct in assuming your test will not work?

Comment: Then **edit** your question to explain why you suspect that.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik Well I stated I have tested all the other components, that's really the only reason why I suspect this component is faulty.  But I don't know what it is, in order to know how to test it.   Thanks for your help, sorry I didn't ask the question correctly.

Comment: "Tested" does not mean you found a fault. You might explain 1. That the PCB is not working correctly. 2. You're trying to *identify a faulty part*. 3. That the circled part cannot be identified. 4. The characteristics, e.g., forward and back resistance. 5. *Where* it is in the circuit... power lead? control lead? etc.

Comment: Every component seems to be labeled, but I don't see a label for the white one. Maybe it's under it?
The letters for it might help identify it.

Comment: @garvamel, thanks I have since removed the part from the board, there is no label unfortunately but the component itself is labelled underneath with F2A.  So I believe its a fuse, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's connected between positive and negative supply it could be a gas discharge tube (GDT).
If it's in series with a supply line, it's probably a fuse.

If I would have to take a guess, it's the latter, since that would be an odd place for a GDT. GDTs are intended to protect against heavy surge voltages and are usually accompanied with other protection devices and located more "upstream" near cables that enter a product from the outside world (mains, communication lines, ...).